# phpcs WordPress ruleset error Detected usage of a non-sanitized input variable: $_FILES

Tags: wordpress, phpcs, phpcodesniffer

I have a function of a file uploading. While uploading a file when I run the PHP_CodeSniffer phpcs I am getting the error. I am running WordPress ruleset.

> Detected usage of a non-sanitized input variable: $_FILES

```
$fext = $file = $_FILES['import_file']['name'];
$filename = $_FILES['import_file']['tmp_name'];
```

Can anyone please tell me how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_file_name

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload $_FILES['import_file'] using wp_handle_upload() should be enough to sanitize it.

Instead of running:

```
$file = $_FILES['import_file'];
$wp_handle_upload($file, array( 'test_form' => false ));
```

Don't hold $FILES['import_file'] in a variable, do this:

```
$wp_handle_upload($_FILES['import_file'], array( 'test_form' => false ));
```